# Exceptions to filters/sorting in ag-grid

Tags: ag-grid

I have a very large set of data that I'm rendering using ag-grid. Without going into too much detail, some elements in the data set have references to others and should be displayed in the grid if the element they are *linked to* passes the filters that are currently applied. So if element A is linked to element B, element A should display if B passes the filters, whether A passes the filters itself or not.

Is there a built-in way to do this with ag-grid without making custom filters for every column? I believe I could just make every column filter by the 'parent' element's values in the case of these linked elements, but that would take a lot of work and I'm wondering if there's a better way.

Additionally, these linked elements would appear in the grid right below the element they're linked to, so for all intents and purposes they would be treated as equal to their parent elements in the case of sorting.

It seems like this kind of functionality might be possible with rowspanning, but ag-grid's rowspanning seems a little clunky to me, in that the documentation itself says that sorting and filtering will behave weirdly when rowspanning is used. Also, implementing rowspanning with ag-grid seems pretty counterintuitive so I would like to avoid it if possible.

(using ag-grid with Angular 6)

Comment: fully unclear - provide a sample pls.

Comment: See [ask] go through how to create [mcve].